# Trying to Implement a simple Jersey Rest Project

Tags: java, xml, rest, maven

I'm trying to implement a simple Jersey rest client

Message.class:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/message")
public class Message {

    @GET
    @Path("/postmsg/{regId}/{msg}")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public Response sendMsg(@PathParam("regId") String regId,@PathParam("msg") String msg) {

        String output ="RegId: " + regId + ", Message: " + msg; 
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }
}
```

Web.xml
I've added jersey dependency in My web.xml as below.

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sample.web.msg</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Pom.xml:
I've added jersey dependency in My web.xml as below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

And when I try to run this url on my browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/GCM/message/postmsg/regId/msg
```

All I get is 
**HTTP Status 404 - /GCM/message/postmsg/regId/msg
**

Can someone please help, what is that I'm missing, thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Jersey servlet is mapped to `/rest/*` but your url is begins with `/GCM/*`.

Either change the servlet mapping to:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GCM/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or access the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/message/postmsg/regId/msg
```